# Fortran MPI (synchronizing an array)

Tags: arrays, merge, fortran, mpi

I am trying to run this simple MPI Fortran 90 code on 4 processors. The problem is that I am not able to merge or synchronize the values of the elements of the array calculated by each processor. Here is the code:

```
PROGRAM TRY
USE MPI


integer status(mpi_status_size)
INTEGER                            I, J, K, II, IERR, MY_ID, NUM_PROCS, PSP
INTEGER     , PARAMETER                 :: GRIDX =8 
REAL        , DIMENSION(gridx)          :: PSI
psi=0
PRINT*, 'YASER'

 call mpi_init(ierr)
 call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,my_id,ierr)
 call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,num_procs,ierr)

 DO I=1+MY_ID*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS, (MY_ID+1)*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS
    PSI(I)=1.0
 END DO

 **IF (MY_ID .NE. 0) THEN
    CALL mpi_send( PSI(1+MY_ID*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS:(MY_ID+1)*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS),GRIDX/NUM_PROCS,mpi_real, 0,10,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
 END IF
 IF (MY_ID .EQ. 0) THEN
    DO II=1,NUM_PROCS-1
        CALL mpi_recv(PSI(1+MY_ID*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS:(MY_ID+1)*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS),GRIDX/NUM_PROCS,mpi_real, &
        II,10,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)
    END DO
 END IF**



 IF (MY_ID .EQ. 0) THEN
    OPEN(PSP,FILE='TRYpsi.txt')
    DO I=1, GRIDX
        WRITE (PSP,*)  PSI(I)
    END DO
    CLOSE(PSP)
 END IF

 CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)
 END PROGRAM TRY
```

However, although each processor does its job correctly and make 'psi' equal to one, the problem is with their communication because when I open the TRYpsi.txt, I see that while the elements of the array calculated by the 0th processor are all equal to one, the other elements are all equal to zero! This means that either the 0th processor has not received the information from the other processors or the other processors have not sent the information to the other processors.

Could you please help me with mpi_send and mpi_recv?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, or if the problem is programming, or configuration.  But this link might help:  http://condor.cc.ku.edu/~grobe/docs/intro-MPI.shtml

Comment: Thanks. I had used the same procedure as the linked suggested

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at your call to MPI_Recv. You are receiving into the same location in each iteration of the loop. What you (probably) want is to change the value of the first argument, depending on the value of II.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your point. However, the reason is that the 0th processor should receive the information from all other processors. That is why I need to define a loop to cover the ID of all processors (from 1 to 3 and NOT zero).

Comment: Yes, i understand that. However in your loop you are not varying the first argument (the recv buffer) of mpi_recv() according to the loop variable - so what happens is that in the second iteration you overwrite the data written  in the first iteration and so on.

Comment: Yes! you are right! I have corrected it and the code works fine! thank you very much

Comment: Another hint: It is much better to use the collective functions in MPI than implementing them by yourself using send/recv in most cases. But of course send/recv is conceptually simpler at first.